# How to embed another website into my own web to keep the same header

Tags: html, iframe, embed

We have a web app that we want to integrate in the websites of several clients by a subdomain, since in most cases we cannot modify their webs. Besides, our web is build in a different language and we want to keep it in our servers.

At the moment, they are adding links on their site's menu to our subdomain, however, they want to keep the same header and the footer so that the user feels that they are on the same website.

For now, we are copying the html and inserting it in our template, but this is not a good solution for the future and we are having several problems due to javascript conflicts.

How can we solve this? An iframe does not allow us to modify its content, I think. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _"An iframe does not allow us to modify its content"_,  you can put the iframe between header and footer. If you want to _edit_ the contents of it, just use javascript. If you need to put there some forms linked to php it will work fine, just remember that every php redirect will change the iframe contents (but it won't touch the header and footer of the outer website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know any good ways to do this client side.

First thought is to have all the pages link your Javascript to create the header/footer, but it's not good to require Javascript to display content.

HTML imports would really be perfect for this, but it not well supported. You can consider if you're willing to use a polyfill, like Google's webcomponents.

I feel like best approach here would be to do this somehow not on client side. Either use a server that lets you use a template engine, or some static site generator that supports templating.